# Can I use Messages with RESTful services using WebHttpBinding?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, message

Can I use Messages with RESTful services using WebHttpBinding?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [message contracts](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2007/05/01/9279.aspx).